# Why am I getting an undefined reference error

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors

My code is currently coming up with compile error which it is finding on line 40 of StackOfBoxes.cpp. The error is an undefined reference error:

> StackOfBoxes.cpp:40: undefined reference to `Box::Box();`

I'm not sure what to do in order to debug. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
bool StackOfBoxes::isEmpty() const
{
    if (m_size == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int StackOfBoxes::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

void StackOfBoxes::push(int value)
{
    Box* box = m_top;
    m_top = new Box();
    m_top->m_value = value;

    m_top->m_previous = box;
    // increase m_size by 1;
    m_size += 1;
}

int StackOfBoxes::pop()
{
    // Create a Box pointer (Box* temp) and store the value of m_previous using m_top
    Box* temp = m_top->m_previous;

    // Similarly store the m_value using m_top into the Integer variable 
    int x = m_top->m_value;

    // Delete top of the stack 
    delete m_top;

    // make the current Box pointer your new m_top
    m_top = temp;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Which is line 40? Why does your code start with a close brace? Please edit your title, it's cut off in the middle of a word.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you will need to provide your full code, preferably a minimal example that exposes the error.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you declared class Box in a separate file, and didn't `#include "Box.h"` in StackofBoxes.cpp.  If that's the case: put the declaration of class Box in a .h file and include it from your cpp file.

Comment: Contrary to comment by @UliKöhler you should provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct/Compilable, Example) rather than the full source which may not be suitable for inclusion in your question.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I agree, but as it is in the current state impossible to find where line 40 is, I think the full code will be better to diagnose than the current state. As I stated before, a minimal example will definitely be better, but I'm not sure if the OP is capable of extracting a SSCCE from the original source.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have declared box with a constructor something like:

```
class box {
public:
    box(void);

};
```

But then not gone on to define the constructor like:

```
box::box(void)
{
    ....
}
```

Either that, or that file isn't being linked in.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is line 40 `m_top = new Box();` The likely reason for this error is that you haven't defined the default constructor.